# MySQL I dont want my SUM CASE to be Null

Tags: mysql, database

I am using a MySQL database and I have a big mysql_query that works completely fine except for this one line.

```
SELECT game_id, 
COALESCE(
SUM(CASE WHEN game_score = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
- 
SUM(CASE WHEN game_score = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) AS score 
FROM .... 
WHERE .... 
GROUP BY ....
```

This line returns me almost all of the numbers that I want, yet they are the same numbers as when I wasn't using the `COALESCE` function.
I would like this statement to return me 0 when there is a `game_id that has an empty`game_score` field.
Where is my code going wrong?

Comment: You know, after answering this question, I realize that the COALESCE does not behave as you intend.  Only the first SUM is being executed, and it should be returning 1 or 0 only based on whether game_score = 1.  Are you thinking that COALESCE will skip over 0s as if they were NULLs?  If so, that is not correct.  You probably want "else NULL" or to drop the else clause entirely from the case statements.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Both SUMs are being executed and the need to be since sometimes I use the code as SUM(.....THEN 5) - SUM(....THEN 3). I just tried both of your ideas to see what would happen; removing the ELSEs or replacing them with ELSE NULL, and both methods return all zeros for score. To answer your question I am hoping to do the opposite. I want COALESCE to skip over the NULLs as if the were 0s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use decode function like this ---

```
SELECT game_id, 
SUM(DECODE(game_score, null, 0, 0, -1, 1, 0)) AS score 
FROM .... 
WHERE .... 
GROUP BY ....
```

I have checked this query for working, its fine
hope it helps you....

Comment: decode function means if game_score is null then score = 0, if game_score = 0 then score = -1 , if game_score = 1 then score = 0; it will add all these values and you will get your desired result.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
when game_score is null then ...
```

### Edit

```
SELECT game_id, case when game_score is null then 0 else
                SUM(CASE WHEN game_score = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                -
                SUM(CASE WHEN game_score = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) end AS score 
FROM games
group by ...
```

See this [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcde5/4)

Comment: I just tried this the way Rahul recommended and it did not work. Is that the way you wanted it to be used?

Comment: @RickRyan: See my update. If that is not working then please modify the SQLFiddle example in a way that it does not work and post the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `is null` like

```
CASE WHEN game_score = 1 THEN 1 
when game_score is null THEN 0
ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: this looks like it should work, and I just tested it, but it doesn't... hmmm

Answer (score 0):

Use the COALESCE function around your field name in your statements instead of surrounding the SUM function:

```
SUM(CASE COALESCE(game_score,0) WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE COALESCE(game_score,0) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: I just tested this and it still isnt returning me the NULLs as 0s. Im starting to think I have another problem. I have no idea what though.

Comment: I tried a simple select using the method above and it provided me the expected result with the null fields that I was have in my test table. It could be related to the filter in the where clause or the way it's being grouped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that game_id can have an empty game_score field in one row and a valid one in another.  Your code picks up the valid one and returns non-null.

Fix this problem by looking for this case explicitly, as the first argument to coalesce:
    SELECT game_id,
           (CASE WHEN count(*) <> count(game_score) then NULL
                 ELSE COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN game_score = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
           . . .

I'm not sure what the coalesce is trying to do.  It seems to be adding one for a bunch of different game_scores.  Can you use one of the following instead:

```
COUNT(game_score) ?

SUM(case when game_score between 1 and xx then 1 else 0 end) ?
```

Comment: I cant use COUNT(game_score) for reasons I described in my reply to your comment above; sometimes I need to use the code as SUM(.....THEN 5) - SUM(....THEN 3). I probably should have lead with an example like that. And SUM(case when game_score between 1 and xx then 1 else 0 end) wouldn't be necessary because game_score is only 0 or 1. Let me do a little research and try your first explanation. It seems makes sense, I just dont understand all of the SQL yet.